# Cannot find dispatch method for operation on weblogic12c

Tags: web-services, java-8, ejb-3.0, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

We have deployed the EJB application, .ear file on weblogic 12c. (Application build on Java 8)
Getting this error for 4 operations of 7 in WSDL.

Same EAR is working fine on weblogic 11g server (Application build on Java 6)

```
<faultstring>Cannot find dispatch method for {http://webservices.vodafone.nl/urapi/subscriberservice/2.0/}setICS</faultstring>
```

Can anyone please help. I can share more details if needed.

thanks in advance !

Comment: is this application built with weblogic 8.1 webservices runtime ?

Comment: No, this application is currently running on weblogic 11g and  now we are migrating on 12c.

Comment: 11g has webservices 8.1 runtime, but in 12c were removed, more info  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24497/upgrade_ws.htm#WLUPG334